# Line equation in complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $L$ the line $x+y=1$. This line in complex plane is $\left\{z:z=x+i(1-x),\ x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ right?
Why $\infty \in L$? I read this in a solved problem but I don't understand this.

The problem and solution is:

Let $L$ the line $x+y=1$ and $C=T(L)$ with $T$ Mobius transformation $T(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$.
a) Show that $C$ is a circle with is not a line.

b)Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Find symmetrical point $z^{*}$ with respect $C$.

Solution. a)It is enough to prove that $C$ is not a line. For this, it is sufficient to prove that  $\infty\in C$.
The unique $z\in\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ such that $T(z)=\infty$ is $z=-1$. Then, because $-1\not\in L,\ \infty=T(-1)\not\in T(L)=C$.

b) Because $1,i,\infty \in L, T(1)=0,\ T(i)=i,\ T(\infty)=1$ are in $C$. Then 
$(z^{*},0,1,i)=\overline{(z,0,1,i)}$ implies $z^{*}=\frac{(1+i)\overline{z}}{2\overline{z}+i-1}.$

Comment: Are you familiar with the stereographic projection of the complex plane? It's easy to see this line contains the point at infinity in that setting.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, that makes no sense. Unless we are working in the context of projective geometry. Is that the case?

Comment: The Moebius transformations take lines and circles to lines or circles. The point at infinity is assumed to be on every line.